# Fetching data between two ISODate from mongodb-spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

Hi in my spring with mongodb project i want to fetch the data between two ISODate .How it is possible? please help me.
The data in the mongodb is like following:

collection name is mycollection and there is a field name creationTime like this:

"creationTime" : {
         "logtime" : ISODate("2013-09-12T08:39:07.227Z"),
         "logtimeStr" : "12-09-2013 02:09:07",
         "day" : 12,
         "month" : 9,
         "year" : 2013,
         "hour" : 14,
         "min" : 9,
         "second" : 7
 }

and now i want to retrieve data from this collection on between two logtime by using spring.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :
Take date from user in dd-mm-yyyy and remove "-" from this and convert it into date by using SimpleDateFormat and Calendar class (also set hr,min and sec by using calendar) and make a query like this:

Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria
            .where("creationTime.logtime").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));